# Help with proof: $\mathrm{rank}(A+B) \le \mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{rank}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

The question is:

> If $A,B$ are any $m\times n$ matrices, prove that $\mathrm{rank}(A+B) \le \mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{rank}(B)$.
>   ($\mathrm{rank}(A)$ is the dimension of the column space of $A$, i.e., the dimension of the subspace of $\mathbb R^m$ spanned by the columns of $A$)

Here is my proof of it. I don't know if it is correct at all, I sort of went on a whim. If it's only slightly flawed could you help tell me what mistakes I have made and if it is completely wrong, any suggestions on how I can go about proving this?

Let $\mathrm{rank}(A) = k$ so that some vectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ form a basis for the column space of $A$.
Let $\mathrm{rank}(B) = r$ where $r\geq k$. By the Basis Theorem, the l.i. set of vectors $\{v_1,...v_k\}$ can be extended to form a basis for the column space of $B$ so that the vectors $\{u_1,\ldots,u_r\}$ with $u_i = v_i$ for each $i=1,...,k$ form a basis for the column space of $B$.

Thus the $j$-th column of $A$, $\alpha_j$ can be written as a linear combination of $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ and the $j$-th column of $B$, $\beta_j$ can be written as a linear combination of $\{u_1,\ldots,u_r\}$ with $u_i = v_i$ for each $i=1,\ldots,k$.
Hence:
$$
\begin{align*}
\alpha_j & = a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_kv_k  \\
\beta_j & = b_1u_1 + \ldots + b_ru_r \\
& = b_1v_1 + \ldots +b_kv_k + b_{k+1}u_{k+1} + \ldots +b_ru_r
\end{align*}
$$

If we let $C=A+B$, the the $j$-th column of $C$, $\gamma_j$ is equal to $\alpha_j + \beta_j$ and thus
$$
\begin{align*}
\gamma_j & = \alpha_j + \beta_j\\
& = a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_kv_k + b_1v_1 + \ldots +b_kv_k + b_{k+1}u_{k+1} + \ldots + b_ru_r\\
& = (a_1+b_1)v_1 + \ldots + (a_k+b_k)v_k + b_{k+1}u_{k+1} + \ldots + b_ru_r
\end{align*}
$$

Since every column of $C$ is a linear combination of $\{u_1,\ldots,u_r\}$ with $u_i = v_i$ for each $i=1,\ldots ,k$ and $\{u_1,\ldots,u_r\}$ by definition is linearly independent, then it forms a basis for the column space of $C$, and thus the rank of $C =A+B$ is $r$.

Therefore

$$
\mathrm{rank}(A+B) = r\\
\mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{rank}(B) = k + r
$$

Thus 
$$\mathrm{rank}(A+B) \le \mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{rank}(B)
$$

QED.

Comment: Notice that by your proof, except when $\mathrm{rank} (A) = k = 0$, strict inequality always holds, which is not generally true, for instance taking $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I have been thinking about this too. I think the problem with the proof is that step of extending {$v_1,...v_k$} using the Basis Theorem to form a basis for the column space of $B$. The Basis Theorem doesn't actually state this, it states something similar but not that. Any advice on how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption $u_i = v_i$ for $1\le i\le k$ is plain wrong. A counter-example is trivially $A = e_1, B = e_2$ with $m=2, n=1$ (i.e. $\{A,B\}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^2$).
For a correct solution, you can simply observe that the column span of $A+B$ is a subset of
$$\langle v_i \mid 1\le i\le \mathrm{rank}(A)\rangle + \langle u_i \mid 1\le i\le \mathrm{rank}(B)\rangle$$
wich has dimension at most $\mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{rank}(B)$ (iff the sum is direct).

This observation is basically what you make in the first half of your proof (where you introduce $\gamma_j$). The rest of the proof is faulty for the reason outlined above.

Comment: Yea I had a feeling that was where the error was. You're absolutely right, doing that was both incorrect and extraneous, you can prove it easily with an observation that's practically already in the proof. Thank you, I should've seen it.

Comment: @Gowrath No problem. While fixing the MathJax in your post (you might want to take a look at it), I noticed the actual misconception is about the basis theorem. You can only extend the Column basis to a basis of all of $\mathbb R^m$, but you have no choice as to what the added vectors will look like. Thus you implicitly assumed that the column spaces of $A$ and $B$ are contained in one another.

Answer (score 2):

That is because $\operatorname{rank}A=\dim\operatorname{Im}(A)$, so 
$$\operatorname{rank}(A+B)=\dim\operatorname{Im}(A+B)$$
On another hand, there is a surjection: $\:\begin{aligned}[t]\operatorname{Im}A\oplus \operatorname{Im}B&\to \operatorname{Im}A+\operatorname{Im}B\\
(x,y)&\mapsto  x+y
\end{aligned}$, and $\operatorname{Im}(A+B)\subset \operatorname{Im}A+\operatorname{Im}B$, so 
\begin{align*}\operatorname{rank}(A+B)=\dim\operatorname{Im}(A+B)&\le\dim(\operatorname{Im}A+\operatorname{Im}B) \\&\le\dim\operatorname{Im}A+\dim\operatorname{Im}B=\operatorname{rank}A +\operatorname{rank}B.\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to think of $m\times n$ matrices as linear transformations $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, and to note that the rank of a matrix is precisely the dimension of its image in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Thus, for two matrices $A,B : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, let $V$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ spanned by the images of $A$ and $B$. If the image of $A$ has basis $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ and the image of $B$ has basis $b_1,\ldots,b_s$ (so that $rank(A) = r, rank(B) = s$), then $V$ clearly is spanned by $a_1,\ldots,a_r,b_1,\ldots,b_s$, so $V$ has dimension at most $r + s = rank(A) + rank(B)$.

Note that for any vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $(A+B)(v) = Av + Bv$, and so the image of $A+B$ is contained in $V$, thus the image of $A+B$ has dimension at most $rank(A) + rank(B)$.

Thus, $rank(A+B)\le rank(A) + rank(B)$.

Comment: MathJax tip: `\mathrm{rank}(A)` produces $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ ;)

Comment: @AlexR All it does is un-italicize it. Not worth the extra effort imo >.>

Comment: Actually it tells MathJax to handle this as a single math entity. The italics are thought of as $r\cdot a\cdot n\cdot k$ :P It's not a big deal here but in more condensed scenarios and in longer texts, it quickly becomes an issue. You can verify this by looking at `r a n k` (note the spaces): $r a n k$

Comment: @AlexR Why does it become an issue? Are you saying that it takes mathjax longer to load or something?

Comment: No, not at all. It becomes a readability issue. `\int fun x dx` is the classic example of what goes wrong.
$$\int fun x dx \ne \int \mathrm{fun}\ x \ \mathrm dx$$

Comment: @AlexR Oh right of course I would never let that happen :-p

Comment: \operatorname{fun} is the right thing to do here, not \mathrm{fun}. This gets the spacing right without the need to add spaces manually.